# General solution of Poisson's equation

Tags: electrostatics, potential, differential-equations

How to find general solution of Poisson's equation in electrostatics.

$$
\nabla^2V=-\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}
$$

Where,
V  = electric potential
ρ  = charge density around any point
εₒ = absolute permittivity of free space.

Comment: This is rather too broad for our format - but you probably want to read up on [Green's functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function).

Answer (score 4):

Poison's equation is a partial differential equation (PDE), so one solves it using the techniques of differential calculus (or something fancier). So, typically, one firstly solves the homogeneous part of the ODE in question and then secondly the non-homogeneous part, and then you combine the two solutions for a general solution. Of course, a charge density, $\rho(x,y,z)$, must be specified in order to solve the non-homogeneous part of the PDE. This is a routine exercise in introductory E&M, meaning there is a lot of information available about it:

Here's an explicit solution of Laplace's equation using the method of Separation of Variables http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/LaplacesEqn.aspx

Here's a solution of Poisson's equation using the method of Green's Functions
http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node31.html

I recommend Griffith's Intro to E&M textbook for further reference into how to solve specific boundary conditions for Poisson's equation, here's a pdf I found online (I hope this is okay to do) http://kestrel.nmt.edu/~mce/griffiths_4.pdf

For further reference into the theory of differential equations, see M. Boas' Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences [https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Methods-Physical-Sciences-Mary/dp/0471198269](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471198269)

A decent intro to Differential Equations book is by R. Haberman [https://www.amazon.com/Applied-Differential-Equations-Boundary-Problems/dp/032179706X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/032179706X)

Edit: using the Green's function approach is usually taught/learned after the Separation of Variables approach. Green's functions require more familiarity with mathematical abstraction than does Separation of Variables. Plus, Separation of Variables allows the student to see the "nuts and bolts" of the ODE without getting lost in uniqueness and reciprocity theorems (especially when considering non-trivial charge distributions). The ardent student should learn the method of Green's functions, however, if they want to pursue graduate school (look in John David Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics).

Comment: "Poison's equation is an ordinary differential equation (ODE)"  Actually, it & Laplace's equation are both partial differential equations (PDEs).

Comment: @D.Halsey I was just about to write this. I think the OP must mean it is an ODE for separable solutions.

Answer (score 2):

See for Poisson's equation

http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node31.html

The general solution for Poisson's equation is
$$ \phi (r) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int \frac{\rho (r')}{|r-r'|}  d^3 r'    $$

Intuitively, decompose $\rho$ into point charges. Then each point charge gets 'smeared out' by 1/r to yield its potential. And finally the individual potentials from the point charges are summed together.

Comment: This is one solution, but not the general solution. You can for example add any constant to it and it will still satisfy the equation.

Comment: You can also add any harmonic function and also get a valid solution not limited to a constant , this will however, change the value of E